# Asset validation failed Invalid Bundle The bundle at '.app/PlugIns/AppWidgetExtension.appex

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, ios-frameworks

I added a local framework to share data between my main app and my widget. The app builds without any issues and I can access the framework from my widget.

When I go to archive the app to upload I get the following errors.

```
Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'SecurePlate.app/PlugIns/SecurePlateWidgetExtension.appex' contains disallowed nested bundles. (ID: 43b70db5-ceb3-44d2-bc25-cd6e61efece2)

Asset validation failed
Invalid Bundle. The bundle at 'SecurePlate.app/PlugIns/SecurePlateWidgetExtension.appex' contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'. (ID: 45bd839a-43a8-428c-932c-fcebd8904120)
```

- In my app target I set `Always Embed Swift Standard Library` to `Yes`
- In my extension I set `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` to `No`

[image]